# Python and ElasticSearch: Convert CSV to JSON with index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I would like to convert a bunch of CSV file to a specific .JSON file format in Python.

This is my sample CSV file:

```
L1-CR109 Security Counter,has been forced,2019-02-26
L1-CR109 Security Counter,has been forced,2019-02-26
L1-CR109 Security Counter,has been forced,2019-02-26
L1-CR109 Security Counter,has been forced,2019-02-26
```

.. and this is my desired json output:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "location" : "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_activity": "has been forced", "2019-02-26"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "location" : "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_activity": "has been forced", "2019-02-26"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "location" : "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_activity": "has been forced", "2019-02-26"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "location" : "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_activity": "has been forced", "2019-02-26"}
```

Currently I was able to produce the following json format result:

```
[{"location": "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_status": "has been forced", "date": "2019-02-21"}, 
{"location": "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_status": "has been forced", "date": "2019-02-21"}, 
{"location": "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_status": "has been forced", "date": "2019-02-21"}, 
{"location": "L1-CR109 Security Counter", "door_status": "has been forced", "date": "2019-02-21"}
```

..and this is my Python code:

```
def csv_to_json():
    in_file = '/Elastic Search/Converted Detection/Converted CSV'
    out_file = '/Elastic Search/Converted Detection/Converted JSON'

    for filename in os.listdir(in_file):
        print("\n")
        print("Converting " + filename + " file...")
        with open(in_file + "/" + filename, 'r') as f:
            if filename.endswith(".csv"):
                reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=("location", "door_status", "date"))
                out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])

                text_file = open(out_file + r'/{}.json'.format(filename[:-4]), 'w')
                text_file.write(out + "\n")
```

I have tried to search for a solution but to no avail. May I know what am I missing in the code? Again can I seek advice on why Elastic Search only allows my desired json output format with the index instead of the normal python format?

Comment: You can get some inspiration from https://github.com/yanxurui/csv2es and https://github.com/rholder/csv2es/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it. Note - you hadn't given your date field a name so I've done that, to make it valid json).

```
import json
import csv
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

index_line = { "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1" } }
with open('input.csv', 'r') as infile, open('outfile.json', 'w+') as outfile:

    inreader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for line in inreader:
        document = OrderedDict()
        document['location'] = line[0]
        document['door_activity'] = line[1]
        document['date'] = line[2]
        json.dump(index_line, outfile)
        outfile.write("\n")
        json.dump(document, outfile)
        outfile.write("\n")

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with the Python pandas package:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

in_file = '/Elastic Search/Converted Detection/Converted CSV'
out_file = '/Elastic Search/Converted Detection/Converted JSON'
index_line = '{"index": {"_index": "test", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "1"}}\n'
```

Reading:

```
df = pd.read_csv(in_file)
```

Or directly from a string:

```
text = "L1-CR109 Security Counter,has been forced,2019-02-26\n"*4
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),header=None)
```

Now write the desired format (note that I've added 'date' so it's a valid JSON):

```
with open('outfile.json', 'w+') as outfile:
    for row in df.to_dict('records'):
       data = json.dumps(dict(list(zip(title,row.values()))))
       outfile.write(index_line+data)
```